# How to save QGIS Project without loading it with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, save, qgz

I wrote a processing tool and as part of the tool, I am zooming to the selected object(s) and exporting (writing) the current state to a `.qgz` file. However, it immediately loads this new `.qgz`  to QGIS and replaces the one which was open when I called the processing tool. I want to save the current state with another name but not load it. Is there any way to do that?

Here is the part of the code where I write `.qgz`

```
# Zoom to Planrahmen
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
initial_canvas = canvas.extent()
canvas.setExtent(feat.geometry().boundingBox())
tgtCanvasScale = round(canvas.scale() + 1500, -3)  # rounds up to nearest 1000 and + another 1000
canvas.zoomScale(tgtCanvasScale)

# Export to .qgz
projectName = "GZP_{}_{}_{}_{}_print.qgz".format(gem_name, int(gzpID), labelGZP, karte_bez)
projectOutTEMP = os.path.join(outDir, projectName)
project.write(projectOutTEMP)

feedback.pushInfo("QGZ {} erfolgreich erzeugt.".format(projectName))

# Zoom back to initial extent
canvas.setExtent(initial_canvas)
initCanvasScale = round(canvas.scale())  
canvas.zoomScale(initCanvasScale)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the project is a singleton and you can only ever have one.

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, I am working with QgsProject.instance(). That's the only way I know actually. Based on your comment, I read https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html . So I have to use the project as standalone objects to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What is QGIS version?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz QGIS 3.10.12

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz so I cannot do what I want to do with an earlier version (than QGIS 3.18)?

Comment: There may be an option somewhere. I have no idea.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I have similar issue

Comment: @SYG unfortunately now